# Cocos2d-iphone,not calling dealloc when replacing scene

Tags: iphone, memory, cocos2d-iphone

This is a simplified version of the problem I'm facing now.
I've made 2 empty CCScene 1 & 2 and added CCLayer 1 & 2 onto their respective scene.
I also added an touches function to switch from scene 1 to scene 2 using CCDirector's replacescene.

However, dealloc was never called during the replace scene.

```
// scene & layer 2 are exactly the same as 1
@implementation MainScene

    -(void)dealloc {
     NSLog(@"scene dealloc");
     [super dealloc];
    }

    -(id)init {
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
      layer = [[MainLayer alloc]init];
      [self addChild:layer];
      [layer release];
      NSLog(@"test: %i", [layer retainCount]); //1
     }

 return self;
}

@implementation MainLayer

-(void)dealloc {
 NSLog(@"layer dealloced");
 [super dealloc];
}

-(id)init {
 self = [super init];
 if (self) {
  self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"test %i", [self retainCount]); //1
 }
 return self;
}

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSLog(@"test %i", [self retainCount]); //2 --> ????
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[SecScene alloc]init]];
}
```

furthermore, the NSLog reported the retaincount of the layer to be 2 when I touch the screen. Is this even suppose to be happening? Can anyone probably tell me what I've done wrong or is it just my misunderstanding that retainCount needs to be 0 before dealloc is called?

This problem is causing my main game program to crash just by switch between various scenes/layers with just static sprites (and some minor actions) over and over again.

Comment: tip: use autorelease and spare yourself a lot of troubles with memory management!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too knowledgeable about cocos2d's contract but shouldn't you release the `SecScene` you alloc in `ccTouchesBegan`on this line: `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[[SecScene alloc]init]]`

I don't see any reason why `replaceScene` wouldn't retain, so now the `SecScene` has a retain count of two when it should have one.

More importantly, if you added `MainScene` in a similar way that would explain why its retain count is one higher than you'd like it to be, so it will never get deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the dealloc gets only called rarely I found - so it is hard to test and get it invoked...

Comment: in that case you are very likely leaking memory by not matching alloc/release ... it's not the fault of the dealloc method, it's what, when and where you alloc/retain/release that's causing dealloc not to be called